# Java SQL Select statement using several variables in WHERE clause

Tags: java, sql, sockets, jdbc, udp

I am writing a simple program using UDP Sockets.I need to input the name of a patient and retrieve its details from the database. The name of the patient is entered in the Doctor class and sent to the Server Class. The Server class then execute a query to retrieve the details of the patient. The problem is in the SQL statement. When I used only the variable firstname it is working fine, but when I put the second variable lastname the PatientRecord variable is NULL.

The Server Class :

```
public class Server {

    public static Connection con;

    public static String PatientRecords;

    public static String QueryPatientInfo(String PatientDetails) throws SQLException {

        System.out.print("\nNew Patient query received:\n");

        String [] PatientDetArray = PatientDetails.split(",");

        String firstname,lastname;

        firstname = PatientDetArray[1];
        lastname  = PatientDetArray[2];

        System.out.println("First Name: "+ firstname);
        System.out.println("Last Name: "+ lastname);

        Statement query = con.createStatement();

        query.execute("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE FirstName = '"+firstname+"'  AND LastName = '"+lastname+"' ");

        ResultSet rs = query.getResultSet();

        String sex;
        String dob ;
        String address ;
        String occupation;
        String phoneno  ;


        if(rs != null){

            while (rs.next()){

                sex = rs.getString("Sex");
                dob = rs.getString("DOB");
                address = rs.getString("Address");
                occupation = rs.getString("Occupation");
                phoneno = rs.getString("PhoneNo");

                PatientRecords = sex + "," + dob + "," + address + "," + occupation + "," + phoneno;
            }

            System.out.print("Patient records successfully retrieved from database !\n\n");

            return PatientRecords;
        }

        else {

            System.out.print("Error occurred patient records not found !\n\n");

            return "Error occurred patient records not found !";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

        // Connecting to database - using xampp

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/patientrecord", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Database is connected !");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Database connection error: " + e);
        }

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8008);

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        byte[] sendData;

        System.out.println("Server ready and waiting for clients to connect...");

        while (true) {

            DatagramPacket receivePacket =  new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            String PatientDetails = new String(receivePacket.getData());

            String message;

            message = QueryPatientInfo(PatientDetails);

            System.out.print(message);

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            sendData = message.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);

            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);

        }
    }

}
```

The Doctor Class :

```
public class Doctor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        // Creating array of bytes to send and receive packet
        byte[] sendData;

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        String request,firstName,lastName;

        request = "query";

        System.out.print("Patient Registration");

        System.out.print("\n\nEnter Patient Details:\n");

        // User input
        System.out.print("First name: \n");

        firstName= inFromUser.readLine();

        System.out.print("Last name: \n");
        lastName = inFromUser.readLine();

        String PatientDetails = request + ","+ firstName + "," +lastName;

        sendData = PatientDetails.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,IPAddress, 8008);

        // Send data packet to server
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

        //Receive data packet from server
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        String PatientRecords =  new String(receivePacket.getData());

        //System.out.print(PatientRecords);

        String [] PatientDetArray = PatientRecords.split(",");

        String sex,dob,address,occupation,phoneno;

        sex = PatientDetArray[0];
        dob = PatientDetArray[1];
        address = PatientDetArray[2];
        occupation = PatientDetArray[3];
        phoneno = PatientDetArray[4];

        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: ");

        System.out.println("Details for patient : " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.println("Sex: " + sex);
        System.out.println("Date of birth: " +dob );
        System.out.println("Address: " + address );
        System.out.println("Occupation: " + occupation);
        System.out.println("Phone number: " + phoneno);

        clientSocket.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Do the first and last name match a record in the database?

Comment: Yes of course, when I write the name in the SQL itself like this : "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE FirstName = 'david'  AND LastName = 'john' "); it works fine. When I used the variable firstname only it works . Only when using both variable it doesn't work

Comment: what `System.out.println("First Name: "+ firstname);
        System.out.println("Last Name: "+ lastname);` print copie past the exact result

Comment: The name received from the Doctor Class, this will be used in the query

Comment: You say it works with firstname only.  What if you do lastname only?  Does it work then?

Comment: oh !! no it's not working with lastname only !! I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when your String have Spaces so to avoid this situation you can use `trim()` like this :

```
query.execute("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE FirstName = '" + firstname.trim() + 
               "'  AND LastName = '" + lastname.trim() + "' ");
```

Your way to set variables is not secure it can make syntax error or cause an SQL Injection so suggest to use [Prepapred Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), this way is more secure so instead your query you can use :

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareCall("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE FirstName = ? AND LastName = ? ");
preparedStatement.setString(1, firstname.trim());
preparedStatement.setString(2, lastname.trim());
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Hope this can work with you.

Comment: Thank you !!!! I use the trim() and it works !!! However,I don't understand why it is necessary because there are no spaces in the names entered.

Answer (score 0):

That clearly means that your `WHERE` condition as below is not matching any records and thus no records fetched. Try running the query in SQL directly and see how many records you get. Or try changing the condition from `AND` to `OR` and that should give you an idea.

```
WHERE FirstName = '"+firstname+"'  AND LastName = '"+lastname+"'
```

BTW, your code is open to `SQL Injection` and thus consider using a parameterized query instead.

Comment: the query return good result when the name is entered manually like this :  WHERE FirstName = 'david'  AND LastName = 'john'