# Cannot insert value to database sqllite CodeOneName

Tags: java, database, sqlite, insert, codenameone

I try to insert some values to my database, but I receive error that is "no such column name1" ,name1 is value I want to insert.

```
Database db = null;
Cursor cur = null;
String name1 = myName.getText();
try{
               db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("qlnd.db");
                   String query = "insert into test (name) values (name1)";
                    db.execute(query);
```

Comment: FYI you should accept the answer as it seems correct. This will give you points on stackoverflow and is the "right thing" to do

Answer (score 2):

You try to add the contents of your variable `name1`, but creating your String that way is literally inserting the word *name1*. *Same with tables and columns, that's why I included them on the answer*.

***Edit: Shai Almog's comment states that String.format isn't avaliable with `codenameone`, so just jump to the second alternative.***

```
String table  = "test";
String column = "name";
String value  = myName.getText(); //f.e: John

String query = String.format("insert into %s (%s) values ('%s')", table,column,value);
```

---

---

An alternative way (*which seems to be valid with `CodeNameOne`*) to add the contents of a variable (and not its name) **is to use the add syntax**:

```
String table  = "test";
String column = "name";
String value  = myName.getText(); //f.e: John

String query = "insert into "+ table +" ("+ column +") values ('"+ value +"')";
```

`query` would be converted to:

**`insert into test (name) values ('John')`**

---

Quoting **Shai** again, another alternative would be using ***Parametrized Queries***, instead of manually formatting the String before the `execute` command. It avoids SQL injection and also guarantees that strings are escaped properly. So, **seems to be the best option**:

```
execute("insert into test (name) values (?)", name1);
```

---

An example of a conditional select would be:

```
String name = "John";
db.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?", name);
```

or

```
String name = "John";
String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '" + name + "'";
db.execute(query);
```

First approach would be the recommended one, just as inserts. Note that also avoids manually inserting the single quotes (' ') in order to declare strings.

Comment: `String.format()` isn't supported in Codename One so the second way will work. Notice that a better way would be: `execute("insert into test (name) values (?)", name1);`.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thanks for pointing this out, I wasn't aware string.format was not supported. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: so I want select one column with condition, I can do it like this, right ?                   
 String a = b.getText();                                                                                              String query = "select gt form mytable where name LIKE ?";                    db.execute(query, a);

Comment: this one also using ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42377385/2148953 --> this one uses both approaches, add syntax and parametrized queries

Comment: yes, your syntax in the comment would also be correct

Comment: @KhoaAnh updated the answer with a select example